# ASP.NET Core - In Visual Studio 2022 for authorize redirects to same url instead of url of Identity Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication

Wrong redirection to same URL with ignoring Authority URL:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
...
options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For fixing this issue just add `options.ForwardChallenge = "oidc";` to your AddCookie part.

Example:

```
.AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
...
options.ForwardChallenge = "oidc";
...
}
```